# Random pieces of ancient hardware not working together (Mac G5, Sun network adapter)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, hardware, powerpc

This is probably some kind of weird esoteric hardware combination but it's not why I did it. It's just what I had lying around. I have a 2x 2ghz Mac G5 and I can't really bring myself to part with it even though I know it's a power drain and inefficient by today's standards. I decided I wanted to set it up to do some routing and installed debian on it, then when I couldn't get it to see my second network adapter, I decided I'd try Ubuntu in case they had some better non-free driver solution going on but it didn't work any better. Ubuntu's still on there.

My network adapter is a Sun GigaSwift Quad Port PCI-X (part no. 501-6738-10). The G5 has PCI-X slots. I can't find any trace of the adapter's existence anywhere. Doesn't show up when i do an lspci or anything. The G5 bios is openfirmware, and I'm not that familiar with its commands and have to try to google anything I want to find out. There was a command, I want to say like "dev / ls" that's meant to list every piece of hardware and the gigaswift doesn't show up. I can power off, pull the card, go into openfirmware, do the command, and I get the exact same list.

I don't know too much about hardware at this level but some googling seemed to indicate that on linux it uses a "cassini" driver but then it also needs a binary firmware. My uninformed speculation is that if the network card's own firmware is being loaded by a driver in the operating system, maybe the card is essentially dead even to the bios until that process is ironed out. I don't know if that makes sense. I did get a file claiming to be a binary firmware and stuck it where it was meant to be but I don't know how to make it see it or do anything with it.

I had the card working under Ubuntu on another box without having to do any kind of additional work to get it running. It just worked out of the box. It was a Sun AMD64 box though.

I don't get any kind of link lights. I would get those before on other systems even when I had driver issues. The hardware seemed to still be able to recognize it was connected.

I tried other slots in the G5. No luck. The adapter still works in the other machine.

In my googling I read somewhere that voltage of the slot vs voltage the card requires could come into play. I don't know what voltage either of those needs but does that ring true to any experts who might still be reading this?

Comment: Since it's `Sun` try `Solaris` to get it working

Comment: @gwillie I don't think there's a version of Solaris that runs on the G5 powerpc chip. I'd be open to a bsd if someone knew for a fact it'd work.

Comment: Voltage could be relevant, yes. PCI has two voltage levels: 5V and 3.3V. Slots that only support one or the other usually have a physical notch so that cards which don't support the other voltage don't fit, however, so it isn't very likely unless the card physically fits in both but doesn't actually support one or the other.

Comment: If the card isn't visible at the OpenBoot level, the operating system won't be able to see it either. There's a pretty good summary of what you can do in OpenBoot at http://firmworks.com/QuickRef.html

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE! [Take a tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with our philosophy, and edit your question to provide more information, as well as better formatting. I'd suggest you changing topic to be an actual question, as well as asking question again clearly at the end of your post. I've read your whole question and I still don't know what you're asking. Making question obvious makes it easier to attract attention - especially when your post is a bit longer.